# Configuring TLS for MB of WSO2AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using wso2am 2.2.0 having separate gateway instances (external and internal). Seems the gateway is publishing traffic / throttling information through a jms queue (port 5672).

Is there a way to configure TLS for the jms traffic between the gateway  and traffic manager?

Reason - one of the gateways will be residing in dmz and there's a requirement for end-to-end encryption in dmz. The Thrift traffic is not using TLS either, but at lease the authentication happens over TLS. Though I am affraid the jms credentials (of the admin user) are sent plaintext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TLS` or `ssl` connection from traffic manager is opened by default. The `ssl` port used by the broker is `8672`. This is configured in the file TRAFFIC_MANAGER_HOME/repository/conf/broker.xml, under the transports section as below.

```
        <sslConnection enabled="true" port="8672">
            <keyStore>
                 <location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</location>
                 <password>wso2carbon</password>
                 <certType>SunX509</certType>
            </keyStore>
            <trustStore>
                <location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</location>
                <password>wso2carbon</password>
                <certType>SunX509</certType>
            </trustStore>
        </sslConnection>
```

You can verify whether the `ssl` port also getting opened by verifying the startup logs of your traffic manager node as below.

```
[2018-10-12 16:00:00,155]  INFO - AndesContextInformationManager Queue Sync [create]: deadletterchannel
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672
[2018-10-12 16:00:00,157]  INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672
[2018-10-12 16:00:00,158]  WARN - InboundDBSyncRequestEvent Recovering node. Adding binding [Binding]E=amq.dlc/Q=deadletterchannel/RK=deadletterchannel/D=true/EX=false
[2018-10-12 16:00:00,159]  INFO - AndesContextInformationManager Binding Sync [create]: [Binding]E=amq.dlc/Q=deadletterchannel/RK=deadletterchannel/D=true/EX=false
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672
[2018-10-12 16:00:00,161]  INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672
[Broker] BRK-1004 : Qpid Broker Ready
```

After confirming this, you have to put the correct host, port values in the gateway node for the JMS connection to traffic manager node. This can be configured using the jndi.properties file in gateway node which is found under API_GATEWAY_HOME/repository/conf/. In there you have to change the broker URL with `ssl` configuration. An example `ssl` configured broker `URL` would be like the below

```
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://<Traffice-Manager-IP>:8672?ssl='true'&ssl_cert_alias='<CERTIFICATE_ALIAS_IN_TRUSTSTORE>'&trust_store=' <PATH_TO_TRUST_STORE>'&trust_store_password='<TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD>'& key_store='<PATH_TO_KEY_STORE>'&key_store_password='<KEYSTORE_PASSWOR D>'';
```